# Getting NullPointerException when trying to hide Actionbar item

Tags: android, button, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar, hide

I'm getting a NullPointerException when I want to hide a Action Button from my Actionbar.
I've got a simple Actionbar and a Navigationdrawer.
I just want to hide the action login button on the right top of the Actionbar when successfully logging in with a login dialog.

**NavigationDrawerFragment:**

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        Log.d("test12","onOptionsItemSelected");
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        {
            Log.d("test12_1","onOptionsItemSelected");

            return true;
        }


        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_login)
        {
            Log.d("test13", "onOptionItemSelected");
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login);
            dialog.setTitle(R.string.title_login);

            login_button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_login);
            username = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.et_username);
            password = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.et_password);

            login_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Log.d("test14", "Login Button geklickt");
                    if (username.getText().toString().equals("root") && password.getText().toString().equals("root")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello " + username.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        login_status = true;
                        updateAfterLogin(); // Updated die Seitenleiste

                        getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // reload Actionbar to hide Symbol

                        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START); // Öffnet den Navigationdrawer
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Wrong Username or Password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            dialog.show();

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

The error appears at line:

> ```
> if(login_status == true)
> {
>     menu.findItem(R.id.action_login).setVisible(false);
> }
> ```

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    Log.d("test11", "onCreateOptionsMenu");
    // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
    // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
    if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
        showGlobalContextActionBar();
    }

    if(login_status == true)
    {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_login).setVisible(false);
    }


    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

**Error:**

```
02-26 23:07:14.548  13034-13034/com.example.vo1umen.kimasys E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.vo1umen.kimasys, PID: 13034
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.MenuItem.setVisible(boolean)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.vo1umen.kimasys.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:408)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:1868)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:1989)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:276)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:276)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:79)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.preparePanel(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:979)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.doInvalidatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:1182)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.access$100(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:79)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase$1.run(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:115)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:792)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:596)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:556)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:778)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `action_login` MenuItem is not found. Check your `R.menu.global` xml file, the item is not on it.

Comment: That's right. The action_login MenuItem is in the R.menu.main xml

Comment: So your problem is you are doing inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu); instead of inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);